# How can i couple item inside a loop?

Tags: c#, loops, if-statement, foreach

I want to couple and show one time two items inside a loop?I tried as follow but i didn't accomplish because specified items showing twice.

```
string item1 = null, item2 = null;
foreach(var item in myCollection)
{
    if(item.Id == 20)
    {
        item1 = item.Value;
    }
    else if(item.Id == 21)
    {
        item2 = item.Value;
    }

    if(item.Id != 20 && item.Id != 21)
    {
        //adding
    }
    else
    {
        if(item.Id !=null && item.Id != null)
        {
            myValue = item1 + item2;
            //This case is normaly because item.Id everytime is full.
            //I tried like this (item.Id == 20 && item.Id == 21) but i don't find any solution. 
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I didn't understand what you're trying to do exactly. Are you trying to eliminate duplicates from a collection, or adding up numbers, or what?

Comment: i want to combine two item as my above comment.

Comment: What does "combine" mean? What does an `item` represent?

Comment: Maybe it would help if you explained the algorithm step by step, in words, since "combine two item" is too vague for us to understand.

Comment: try (item.Id == 20 || item.Id == 21) cause if you use && it will never be true cause you're in a loop

Comment: What are you exactly want to do? concatenate the string or add the values? if string then item.ToString() + item2.ToString()

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Presuming that:

1. You have a collection of items defined as `{ int Id, string Value }`,
2. You want to find two items with `Id`s of `20` and `21`,
3. You want to concatenate their string values into a new string,

You can simply use LINQ:

```
var myValue = "";

// find the item with Id == 20 (if it exists)
var item1 = myCollection.FirstOrDefault(i => i.Id == 20);

// find the item with Id == 21 (if it exists)
var item2 = myCollection.FirstOrDefault(i => i.Id == 21);

// if both items are found, join their values into a new string
if (item1 != null && item2 != null)
    myValue = item1.Value + item2.Value;
```

For a more general problem (*"concatenate all items with certain IDs"*) you can rewrite this as:

```
// list of all IDs you want to find
var idsToFind = new[] { 20, 21, 22, 23 };

// find items with corresponding IDs
var items = myCollection.Where(i => idsToFind.Contains(i.Id));

// concatenate results
var myValue = string.Concat(items);
```

Answer (score 1):

It is hard to tell what exactly you are trying to achieve. If you give more details, I will update the answer accordingly.

I'm guessing you have a problem with:

```
(item.Id == 20 && item.Id == 21)
```

This will never in any 'normal' situation evaluate to true since it is not possible for item.Id to be both 20 AND 21 at the same time.
(There are some 'exotic' situations where another thread could update item.Id from 20 to 21 right after the first comparison so that this line evaluates to true).

Maybe what you need is to use `||` instead of `&&`:

```
(item.Id == 20 || item.Id == 21)
```

Comment: @Gigi I am talking about his comment, where he says 'I tried it like this'

Comment: Right, didn't see that.

Answer (score 1):

If by combine you mean concatenating string then try this

```
string item1 = null, item2 = null,myValue = "";
foreach(var item in myCollection)
{
    if(item.Id == 20)
    {
        item1 = item.Value;
    }
    else if(item.Id == 21)
    {
        item2 = item.Value;
    }

    if(item.Id != 20 && item.Id != 21)
    {
        //adding
    }
    else
    {
        if(item.Id !=null)
        {
            myValue = myValue + item1 + item2;

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This won't work. First of all, `myValue` is initially null and accessing it will throw a `NullReferenceException`. Next, `(item.Id !=null && item.Id != null)` could simply be written as `(item.Id !=null)`, but is more likely a typo and was supposed to be `(item1 !=null && item2 != null)`. Nothing else makes sense since `Id` is almost certainly a plain `int` and cannot be null, so OP wants to check if string values of `item1` and `item2` are non-null before concatenating them.

Answer (score 1):

There seems to be a typo in the last else branch:

```
if (item.Id !=null && item.Id != null)
```

Probably you wanted to check item1 and item2 for not being null?